# Go create struct from XML

Tags: go, struct

Please see this playground: https://play.golang.org/p/FOMWqhjdneg
As you can see I have a XML response which I want to unmarshal into a `Product` struct. The XML has an `"assetBlock"` which contains nested nodes and extract data to Product struct. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What do you want to parse from the XML? Do you need to model the complete XML document?

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the body of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a struct for `AssetBlock` and all of the types below it, I've done it up to `group` to show you what I mean:

https://play.golang.org/p/vj_CkneHuLd

```
type Product struct {
    GlobalID   string     `xml:"globalId"`
    Title      string     `xml:"title"`
    ChunkID    int        `xml:"gpcChunkId"`
    AssetBlock assetBlock `xml:"assetBlock"`
}
type assetBlock struct {
    Images images `xml:"images"`
}
type images struct {
    GroupList groupList `xml:"groupList"`
}
type groupList struct {
    Groups []group `xml:"group"`
}
type group struct {
    Usage string `xml:"usage"`
    Size string `xml:"size"`
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Really helpful. However, I tried to enter the `asset`-part, but for some reason I can't figure out how to get the urls. See this playfround: https://play.golang.org/p/t6X2xbQ1PNT

Comment: You need to capitalize the property names:
https://play.golang.org/p/AUnvdlkgq2E
any lower case first letter is private in go and will be ignore by the XML encoders.

Comment: That's it! Damn... thanks, everything works fine now.